# QCD gluon physical polarisation sum in the three gluon vertex

Tags: quantum-field-theory, polarization, quantum-chromodynamics, gauge

In the Compton scattering quark($p_1$) + gluon ($q_1$)-> quark($p_2$) + gluon($q_2$), there is three gluon vertex contribution. If we choose the physical polarisation sum 
$\sum_{\lambda} \epsilon^a(\lambda) \epsilon^{*b}(\lambda)=-g^{ab}+\frac{(p_1^a q_1^b+p_1^b q_1^a)}{(p_1.q_1)}$ for the incoming gluon, and $\sum_{\lambda} \epsilon^a(\lambda) \epsilon^{*b}(\lambda)=-g^{ab}+\frac{(p_2^a q_2^b+p_2^b q_2^a)}{(p_2.q_2)}$ for the outgoing gluon. 
Then, how does this affect the propagator of the virtual gluon in the three gluon vertex? should it be $\frac{-i g_{ab}}{(q_1-q_2)^2}$ ?

Comment: What are you choosing for your polarization vectors?  Once you've made that choice, then you can explicitly calculate the relevant sum over all polarizations (which makes up the numerator of the propagator).  That said, you seem to be using a convention similar to Greiner's QCD book, Eqs. 8 and 9 in Example 5.1, which might be able to help.